# A real-word synonym for the non-word "trustedness"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, is-it-a-word

I always thought that *trustedness* was a word, but apparently it isn't. What's a real word that means the same thing, namely *the quality of being trusted*? Note that this is a different meaning from *trustworthiness*, which means *the quality of being deserving of trust*, not of actually being trusted.

To clarify, I am looking for a word which divorces *popular* judgment from my *personal* judgment. If 99% of people trust a person, but I don't, I would say that he is *trusted*, but not, in my opinion, *trustworthy*. I'm looking for a noun form of the former specifically, or a synonym if it doesn't exist (I don't think it does).

Comment: What precisely do you want to say? You need to provide a context before asking a question. This is too open-ended. "He's trusted" is good enough. "She possesses the quality of trustedness" is pompous and pretentiously prolix. "They're reliable" isn't much different in meaning or connotation: somebody trusts them because somebody says that they're reliable. Give us an example of what you'd like to say, please.

Comment: I'm trying to automatically determine how an author of a scientific article feels about the articles he cites. That is, I'm trying to determine (using sentiment analysis) how much one article "trusts" another. It would be nice to have a word for that metric.

Comment: I think there's a difference between reliability (or trustworthiness) and trustedness, since if I say an article is trustworthy, it implies that I think it's a good article. If I say that it's trusted, I mean that *other people* think that it's a good article.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak You should be adding all this pertinent information to the question.

Comment: I've been reading scientific articles (mostly biomedical) every day for the past 15 years & can't remember ever seeing scientists making overt value judgments about the work of their colleagues. When they do, they usually say simply that "our results & theirs contradict each other. Perhaps that's because of different study populations, testing methods, or XYZs". The fact that a scientist cites an article is no indication of trust, just that it supports the author's point. It's persuasion, not sentiment. One phrase that comes to mind, though: _seminal article_ = **Trust**.

Comment: @BillFranke Agreed. Sentiment analysis in news and literature is *far* easier than in scientific articles. A scathing rebuke in science could look like very gentle criticism outside of a journal. That's why the project is so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I'd opine that "trustedness' has its place as a real word, even if not in the sense that some may use it. In some cases it seems to be the bests word available for the job.

Consider an organisation assessing the degree to which various Banks are trusted by  customers. Their client believes that they are "top dog" in the field and wish to use the slogan "The world's most trusted bank." They devise a rating scale that takes various factors into account to assess the "degree of trustedness" which a bank has achieved. This could certainly be expressed differently such as degree to which they are trusted, % of respondents who said the bank was highly trusted etc, but "trustedness" seems to be a wholly meaningful and understandable term for use in such a situation and I cannot think of another word which better encompasses the shades of meaning which are intended in this case.

---

A webs search indicates that the term 'trustedness' is used, with clear intent and  without explanation, in a computer security context.  That suggests it may be a "real word" that the dictionaries have 'not quite yet caught up with'.

Comment: While it’s true that English is a living language, I don’t know if we necessarily should go adding definitions that are specific to the jargon of a particular industry, or to management-speak, or the like. For example, I’ve met plenty of folks with MBAs who treat the word “action” as a verb.

Comment: @Ascendant Actually, *action* has been used as a verb as early as 1844 in the legal sense. The MBA sense is more recent, but it's already been in use since at least 2004.

Answer (score 2):

If the context of “trustedness” is how much a specific entity A trusts a specific entity B, I’d opt for a phrase like “level of trust” or “degree of trust.”

“Trustworthiness” is good if you’re not really specific about who entity B is trusted by. Related synomyms such as “reliability” “loyalty” etc. are more specific and likely preferable in cases where they are appropriate to the context.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some:

> reliability, fidelity, faithfulness, loyalty, dependability

Which one you want exactly really does, as mentioned in the comments, depend on context, but this list should give you a start.

Comment: If I say that something is any of these, it functions as my own endorsement. What I'm looking for is a metric of other people's opinions, divorced from my own.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak, does it work to say that you are gauging the article's *dependability* or *reliability*? I can see that the others I listed wouldn't work, but I wrote my answer shortly before you provided the clarification in the comments. I do see that what you're after is quite precise.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak: Give us an example sentence & use [X] as the mystery word. That will help. JAM is asking for exactly what I asked for, but you aren't giving it.